# I need to replace Subjects ex :- Subjects :***** but it is giving the output :- Subjects :*****Computer

Tags: perl

Here you can see my code is replacing the subjects with `*****`
but what is happening is it is not replacing the second line.
I have been trying to do this, but failed every time. if anyone could help me out please check

The output I want is:

```
Name : Piyush Prasad
Class : 12th
Stream : Science
Subjects :*****
Text : what ever happens to this code does not even matter to me 
Time :*****
```

and the output what I am getting is:

```
Name : Piyush Prasad
Class : 12th
Stream : Science
Subjects :*****Computer
Text : what ever happens to this code does not even matter to me 
Time :*****
```

Here is the code:

```
 my $fm_log= "
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Name : Piyush Prasad
 Class : 12th
 Stream : Science
 Subjects : Physics Chemistry Maths
            Computer
 Text : what ever happens to this code does not 
        even matter to me 
 Time : 10.304534
 ";
 my %fm_info;
 $fm_log =~ s!.*?(---------------)!$1!s;
 $fm_log =~ s!vwmg.*!!sg;
 my @fm_log = split(/-------+/, $fm_log);
 @fm_log = grep {! m!^\s*$!s} @fm_log;
 for (my $i = 0; $i < @fm_log;$i++){
     my $type = undef;
     my @tmp1 = split(/\R+/,$fm_log[$i]);
     foreach (@tmp1)
       {
         $_ =~ s!^\s+!xxxx! if $_ !~ m!:!;
         $_ =~ s!(Time\s+:)\s+.*!${1}xxx!;
         $_ =~ s!(Subjects\s+:)\s+.*!${1}xxx!;
       }
      $fm_log[$i] = join("\n",@tmp1);
      $fm_log[$i] =~ s!\R+xxxx!!mg;
       }
      print @fm_log;
```

Comment: You don't actually have literal asterisks `****` in your code. Please show your _real_ code.

Comment: You have fields that contain line breaks, and the "field separator" is that a new field begins with a word at the beginning of a line, followed by a colon. Therefore you cannot use such things as `.*` to delete content unless you separate the fields first.

Comment: I assume you are not trying to edit strings this way, by first typing them in and then changing them, but rather you are reading them from a file. I would suggest elaborating on that for a complete solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting

```
Subjects :*****Computer
```

instead of

```
Subjects :*****
```

Is that you split the original string on linebreaks `\R+` and then edit the lines, after which you join the string back together. Since `Computer` is on a new line, it does not get edited.

```
 my @tmp1 = split(/\R+/,$fm_log[$i]);         # <---- splitting the line
 foreach (@tmp1) {                            # editing the pieces
     $_ =~ s!^\s+!xxxx! if $_ !~ m!:!;
     $_ =~ s!(Time\s+:)\s+.*!${1}xxx!;
     $_ =~ s!(Subjects\s+:)\s+.*!${1}xxx!;
 }
 $fm_log[$i] = join("\n",@tmp1);              # joining the pieces
```

In other words, if you have a string such as:

```
my $str = "foo: bar\nbaz";
```

Then split the string on newline and try to remove everything after `foo:`

```
my @pieces = split /\R+/, $str;
```

Now `@pieces` will contain this:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'foo: bar',
      'baz'
    ];
```

And if we try to edit them with `s/foo:.*//`, we will never affect the `baz` part of the original string.

Since you have a file that contains fields separated by lines that start with word(s) followed by a colon, followed by content that may contain newlines, what you need is to first separate the fields from each other.

Your fields look something like...

```
TITLE : CONTENT
        CONTENT ...
TITLE : CONTENT ...
```

There may be modules that read this format that are more suitable. I made up this quick hack to coerce the data into a hash, where you can edit the fields by simply assigning new values to them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fm_log= " Name : Piyush Prasad
 Class : 12th
 Stream : Science
 Subjects : Physics Chemistry Maths
            Computer
 Text : what ever happens to this code does not 
        even matter to me 
 Time : 10.304534
 ";

my @info = split /^ *([\w ]+) : /m, $fm_log;   # split into fields
s/\s+/ /g for @info;                           # cleanup start
s/^\s+|\s+$// for @info;
shift @info;                                   # cleanup complete
my %info = @info;
print Dumper \%info;                 # show the data structure we made

$info{Subjects} = "****";
$info{Time} = "****";

printf("%s : %s\n", $_, $info{$_}) for qw(Name Class Stream Subjects Text Time);
```

This will output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Class' => '12th',
          'Stream' => 'Science',
          'Time' => '10.304534',
          'Subjects' => 'Physics Chemistry Maths Computer',
          'Text' => 'what ever happens to this code does not even matter to me',
          'Name' => 'Piyush Prasad'
        };
Name : Piyush Prasad
Class : 12th
Stream : Science
Subjects : ****
Text : what ever happens to this code does not even matter to me
Time : ****
```